# problem uploading image to Azure cloud deployed application - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, asp.net-web-api2

With the below code I keep getting the error:
When I publish this web API on local IIS and upload the image from `xamarin` to server this code working well, not getting an error but when publishing the API azure cloud I am facing below error. Please help me if anybody knows

> {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version:
>   4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=7c5bdbe4510de6d1a2b16faa5f8c48d98b00f39fe983a5eac89ec12520de616b;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=mitsppk.azurewebsites.net
>   Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 07:28:08 GMT Expires: -1 Content-Length: 0 }}

API code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        { 
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {              
                return BadRequest();
              }
            string PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/ComplaintSystemApp/");           
            CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);           
            List<string> files = new List<string>();

            try
            {                          
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));                 
                    newstreetLightComplaintImg.ImgPath = files[0];

                }


                return Ok();               
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest();

            }
        }
```

Upload imge from xamarin andriod :

```
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
      var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
       fileContent.Headers.ContentType = 
       MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
             ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "file",
                    FileName = "abc.png"
                };
                string boundary = "---8d0f01e6b3b5dafaaadaad";
  MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new 
               MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
                multipartContent.Add(fileContent);
            var response = await 
 client.PostAsync("http://IPaddress/website/api/Img",multipartContent);
     var responsestr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to hit this azure API with postman or fiddler?

Comment: Not yet, locally i tried from postman and andriod logic its working well so i think it should be work on azure when i publish on azure.

Comment: Not actually a lot changes when you move from local IIS to Azure please try using postman and see if that works or not

Comment: Getting the error when i tried with postman. I thing some certification problem with https . i am right .                                                                                                           Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://mitsppk.azurewebsites.net/api/AppApiStreetLightComplaintImgUplaod.
Why this might have happened:
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy

Comment: I had a feeling this must be the issue check this out i guess : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/certificate-pinning-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Let me try to solve this problem ..Thanks

Comment: Well SSL certificates with Xamarin can get you a 1000 blogs

Comment: You share with me certification planing in Xamarin form  but unfortunately Other post method in xamarin andriod is working well just i got the problem with uploading the image to azure.Do you why this error coming just when i upload the image to server.

Comment: Happens only when you try to upload the image? else always works?